# Fixing the max-height in resizable textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

I want to fix the max height and the max width of my resizable textarea.

```css
textarea {
  width:70%;
  max-width:70%;
  height: 40%;
  max-height:60%;
  }
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

The max width is fixed but the height no ! How to fix that using css ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix max-width to 500px and max-height to 100px in your resizable textarea.
Change the values of max-width and max-height accordingly.

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  max-width:500px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you size textarea's main div?

You can find the solution here:

```css
body {
  background:#ddd;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.getDiv {
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
  background:red;
}
textarea {
  height:25%; /* 50px */
  width:25%; /* 100px */
  max-height:50%; /* 100px */
  max-width:50%; /* 200px */
  }
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="getDiv">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</body>
```